# Kernel# gets stuck and Kernel#system does not when issuing gzip without any options

Tags: ruby, linux, gzip

Long story short, I've been working on a project and I noticed that when I use:

```
1.9.3p392 :001 > `gzip`
IRB::Abort: abort then interrupt!
    from (irb):1:in `call'
    from (irb):1:in ``'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

it will wait indefinitely until I CTRL + C.

Although, when I use:

```
1.9.3p392 :047 > system('gzip')
gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression.
For help, type: gzip -h
 => false
```

It will continue without me using CTRL + C

Why does using the backticks stop the process from continuing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backticks operator implicitly redirects the standard output of the resulting subshell (which it does to capture the subshell's output) while `system` doesn't. You can observe the same hang using `system` as follows:

```
system('gzip > /tmp/foo')
```

This explicitly captures standard output and will hang in the same way.

When `gzip` has its output redirected it will wait for input until an `EOF` or other signal is received. Without output redirection it will issue the error message you mention. You can get the same effect from a regular `bash` shell:

```
$ gzip
gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression.
For help, type: gzip -h
```

And:

```
$ gzip > /tmp/foo
...
```

Where `...` indicates that `gzip` will hang until it receives an appropriate signal.

Comment: Thanks Richard! That definitely answered my question.